# Combine records in a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a referrals table which creates a new record for each unique referral that is made. For example, if a patient is referred to GI AND ENT in the same day, there will be two records in the table, one for each referral.

I currently have a query set up to pull all referrals 45 days after the date it was made which triggers staff to send a reminder letter to the patient. A mail merge word document then pulls in the patient information and referral specialty into the document. My current problem is that if a patient was given more than one referral, that will generate multiple letters. Ideally, I would like to generate ONE letter with each of the specialties listed.

Any ideas on how to program a query to combine duplicate patients into one record so that the mail merged letter pulls in all specialties into one letter?

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206870/ms-word-import-table-with-query-condition-based-on-merge-field/34207824#34207824 but the solution offered there should probably be the first thing you try.

Comment: The link @bibadia gives you is a definite possibility, especially if you want a Table result. An alternative, with an Access query, would be an "active" query that concatenates the "many" side into a single string value as the content of a "field". The tricky part with this approach, in mailmerge, is that only a DDE connection can give you the result of an "active" query. The alternative is to use a "Make Table" query which you'd need to run prior to performing the mail merge. The merge is then linked to the table, where the data is static, so any connection method works.

Comment: Then there's also the approach set out in this KB article, but it's a bit complicated to set up: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211303

Comment: @CindyMeister so your first option seems doable. I could, theoretically, trigger the make table query automatically every time the form loads or something. Could you help me understand what you mean by "active" query, why it requires a certain type of connection, and how I would go about doing the concatenation? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An approach one rarely sees, that can yield a more flexible result than a Database field (a table), involves concatenating the one-to-many portion of the data as part of an aggregate query, using a VBA function.

I call this an "active" query - it's not a technical term, just the one I use.

Mail merge can link to such a query directly, but only when using the DDE connection. That was replaced as the default connection method around 2003 by OLE DB and since that time, DDE is not so reliable. DDE is required because the VBA function can only run in the Access application environment. OLE DB (and ODBC) connect directly to the data, so VBA can't run.

That's why using a Make Table query is a more robust approach, these days.

I've been ransacking my memory for the past half-day, trying to dredge up the details - last time I did this was over a decade ago. I've put the main parts together, and tested them, and it goes something like this:

1. Assume you have a database that collect course data, as well as course participants, linked in a one-to-many table of course ID and participant ID.
2. As a mail merge result, you want a list of participants for each course.
3. Requirements:

   - An aggregate query that groups on CourseID and uses the VBA function as an Expression to concatenate a list of names, separated by vbCR (new paragraph in Word). (This will be turned into a MakeTable query for non-DDE connection.)
   - The VBA function that accesses a Recordset to retrieve the particpants for the given CourseID
   - (Optional) a query for the Recordset used by the VBA function

**Aggregate Query** - the SQL (Make Table query):

```
SELECT Kurse.[Kurs ID], concatData([Kurse.Kurs ID]) AS ListOfNames
FROM [Teilnehmer-Adressliste] INNER JOIN (Kurse INNER JOIN [Kurs/Partizipation] 
  ON Kurse.[Kurs ID] 
    = [Kurs/Partizipation].[Kurs ID]) 
  ON [Teilnehmer-Adressliste].[Participant ID] 
    = [Kurs/Partizipation].[Participant ID]
GROUP BY Kurse.[Kurs ID];
```

**VBA code**:

```
Public Function concatData(s As String) As String
    Dim retVal As String

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("testKursAndNames", dbOpenDynaset)
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs.Fields("Kurs ID").Value = s Then
           retVal = retVal & rs.Fields("P_Name").Value & vbCr
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    concatData = retVal
End Function
```

**Recordset query** - SQL:

```
SELECT [Kurs/Partizipation].[Kurs ID], [Teilnehmer-Adressliste].P_Name
FROM [Teilnehmer-Adressliste] INNER JOIN [Kurs/Partizipation] 
  ON [Teilnehmer-Adressliste].[Participant ID] 
    = [Kurs/Partizipation].[Participant ID];
```

4. The mail merge is set up to connect to the table generated by the Make Table query (assuming OLE DB or ODBC connection). In the described case, the table has two fields: the course ID and the list of names.

[image]

Showing the data:

[image]