# Table with variable number of rows in MS Office mail merge

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

Suppose I have a table in MS Excel with columns `Name`, `Number`, and some other columns. `Number` is a positive whole number.

What I would like to do is do a mail merge, each row of the Excel table corresponding to a different record, with an MS Word document containing a table where the number of rows in the table is `Number+1` (1 for the header row); each of the rows will have a number from 1 to `Number`, with the rest of the cells in each row being blank. How do I do this?

I have tried some many-to-one mail merge add-ins I found online, but since each row of the Excel table corresponds to one record in the mail merge, this is in a way actually a one-to-one mail merge.

If versions matter, suppose that we're working with Office 2016.

Comment: As far as I know, you'll need a macro in VBA to get this mailmerge. If you can code in VBA, start your code and come back here with specific questions. If you do not know anything about VBA, I'm afraid you'll have to do it yourself, or using add-ins, or hire a developer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Word, Import Table with Query Condition Based on Merge Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206870/ms-word-import-table-with-query-condition-based-on-merge-field). This is basially the same question, so the Answer should give you the information you need..